# Mapping Profile Property to OptionSet or Picklist Attribute

Tags: sitecore, dynamics-crm-2013, sitecore7

Configuring the CRM Security Provider Module I'm facing the problem of how to map a Sitecore Profile Property to a MS CRM Dynamics OptionSet or Picklist attribute.

The according Developer's Guide doesn't provide any useful hint on this type of mapping.

I tried

```
<add type="System.String" name="Salutation" customProviderData="crm|salutation"/>
```

but obviously the `type` doesn't match the attribute returned from MS CRM - even if the documentation claims that a mapping for a Two Options Attribute should look like this:

```
<add type="System.String" name="DoNotEmail" customProviderData="crm|donotemail"/>
```

Comment: Hi. I'm facing the same problem. I'm trying to map Optionset attributes to a profile property. I tried it first to map onto a sitecore checkbox. However, the checkboxes didn't get checked and furthermore, on saving the user the empty checkboxes cleared all the values in CRM.
When I mapped the attributes to textfields on the profile, the values of the CRM attributes did get filled in on the textfields. But the values where the strings "True" or "False". So, I suppose that sitecore just can't map these values (True & False) onto his own checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I have definitely seen some issues with field mapping between Sitecore and Dynamics. The checkbox field in Sitecore did seem to map properly to the "Two Options" field in Dynamics out-of-the-box for me but I did see issues with the following field mappings.

- DateTime (Sitecore) --> Date & Time (CRM)
- String (Sitecore) --> Money (CRM)
- String (Sitecore) --> Option Set (CRM)

Sitecore support was able to provide a patch to fix the field mappings listed above.

Unfortunately everything is mapped to string values in the Sitecore profile fields which means you cannot map to more complex fields like the Droplink. I'm looking to extend the field mappings to allow a Droplink field to be mapped to an Option set in the CRM.

Note: Using Sitecore 7.0 and CRM Module 2.0.0 rev. 130731

Comment: I'll check the revision of our CRM Module installation and see if mentioned patch will solve our issue.

Answer (score 0):

The two option in MS Dynamics is a boolean. You should try to map to that datatype

Comment: It's funny that the documentation claims that it should be mapped to System.String. I'll check if the patch revision Scott Mulligan mentions in his answer will solve my OptionSet mapping issue - the Two Options wasn't the actual problem (yet).